# What is the best way to know current attack for a server machine?

Tags: linux, audit

I'm hosting centos 7 servers which are exposed to the risk of malicious attacks.
I have to protect the machines from the attacks.
What is the best way to know

- how to protect attacks from system level
  and
- what kinds of attacks are exist up to date?

Thank you

Comment: Scan results from a tool like Nessus

Comment: You are asking for too many things and giving too few information... We only know the OS, but not what kind of "server": web, application, database, gopher...

Answer (score 2):

To prevent attacks, there are many tools and techniques you can use. I can't really go into all of that here. A fast few tips to get started:

- Update everything
- Configure your firewall
- Configure user permissions and make sure processes that don't need root run as a user with minimal amount of permissions
- Configure any network facing services (those you allowed on the firewall)
- Consider if you need some sandboxing, such as firebird
- Consider getting an [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system) and configure it properly

As for what kinds of attacks exist, one of the best places to look would be the [CVE Database](https://www.cvedetails.com/). You should also follow bulletins from your CSIRT.